# Failed to import ng2-dragula with jspm

Tags: drag-and-drop, angular, jspm, dragula

I was trying to inject https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-dragula to Angular2 project ruled with JSPM package manager. But when I import it main boot.js file fails to compile... The only solution I'd found before was to move the project to webpack management. Are there any other solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Just Make sure you include .js files of dragula in index.html and configure the SystemJS Path Too.

```
<script src="/node_modules/dragula/dist/dragula.min.js"></script>
<script src="/node_modules/ng2-dragula/bundles/ng2-dragula.js"></script>


<script>
    System.config({
    paths:{
        'dragula'         : '../node_modules/dragula/dist/dragula.min.js'
    },
    packages: {
      app: {
        format: 'register',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      }
    }
  });
System.import('app/main')
      .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
</script>
```